# php preg_match_all finds empty matches

Tags: php, regex

I'm having an error I don't understand after searching around the web for a couple hours.
I have an SQL request made through ajax query with `POST` method, and generated for the different pages of my website, even sometimes with a direct user input.

To avoid SQL injections, I want to check the content of the parameters.
I can't use PDO::quote() because some parameters can contain lists or SQL function : for example : the `select` parameter can contain `c.id_client, c.nom, COUNT(c.id_client)...`

To prevent SQL injection I'm blacklisting some SQL keywords and functions with `preg_match_all();`

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('"[\w% ]*(add|alter|create|delete|drop|exec|insert|set|table|truncate|update|view)[\w% ]*"[^:]', $inputs, $matches);
```

In the case I'm testing, `$inputs` is the json_encoded post array :

```
{"select":"c.id_client, c.prenom, c.nom, c.email, COUNT(t.actif) AS nombre_licences","from":"clients","as":"c","inner":{"1":{"cond":{"1":{"join_in":"cl.id_client","join_out":"c.id_client"}},"table":"clients_licences","as":"cl"},"2":{"cond":{"1":{"join_in":"t.id_client_licence","join_out":"cl.id_client_licence"},"2":{"join_in":"t.actif","join_out":"1"}},"table":"terminaux","as":"t"}},"where":{"1":{"index":"CONCAT_WS('', c.prenom, c.nom, c.email, c.siren)","operand":"LIKE","value":"%necas%"}},"group":{"1":{"index":"c.id_client"}},"order":{"1":{"index":"c.nom"},"2":{"index":"c.id_client"}},"offset":"0","limit":"3","resultFormat":"<tr class=\"result\"><td>$$id_client##<\/td><td>$$nom## $$prenom##<\/td><td>$$email##<\/td><td>$$nombre_licences##<\/td><td><button class=\"btn btn-xs btn-success\" onclick=\"location.href='\/admin\/view\/$$id_client##'\" ><i class=\"fa fa-search\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><\/i> Voir<\/button><\/td><\/tr>"}
```

And then I get :

```
$matches = [[], []]
```

I tested this a couple times on different regex testers like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L52BBN/1) without getting any match...

Please note that I can't modify this code too much.

Thanks for the help, Jm56Z

_

**EDIT:**

It seems like preg_match_all() sets `$matches` to an array containing two times the matches array :

```
$matches = [[matches], [matches]]
```

Comment: Is this about `PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given…` perhaps? How did you get `$inputs`? Is that the literal AJAX request and prepared by the client-side query generator? Or did you use an SQL query parser in PHP for that? If so, the basic regex command blacklist wouldn't make much sense, if you already got everything split up into `"select":` anyway.

Comment: I use the post method for my ajax.
This verification is the  first thing I do with the inputs.
I use `json_encode()` on the post array first.
I only blacklist sql keywords on the values (because the index are 'select', 'from', and so on...)

Comment: I'm afraid you have an application design that's terribly difficult to secure, if not impossible. If you have a tool to submit random SQL code to the server, the only serious security you can implement is whatever you can accomplish by restricting the privileges of the MySQL user than runs the code. It's like giving the keys of your home to some stranger: checking him for a list of banned items is pretty useless; at most, you can lock some rooms.

Comment: Alvaro You're right, and this is why the main sql call is `SELECT` and can't be modified, and then I prevent the use of nested SQL calls.
I do what I can to reduce the amount of code in the website (which is already very big)

Comment: I have to say I agree with @ÁlvaroGonzález, the design you've described is really bad. I can appreciate what you're trying to do, but even ignoring the direct sql security issues you're likely to have, it's really poor application architecture to allow that kind of flexibility in your API. Write the queries locally and have API endpoints that call them. If you really need the external application to be able to write their own queries to that level, then maybe they should have actual access to the database as your PHP system likely isn't acheiving much other than being a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

`preg_match_all()` puts all matches in a multidimentional array even if it doesn't find any.
By default :

```
[[matches of the full regex], [matches of group 1], [matches of group 2]...]
```

Next time I'll read documentation with more attention.
https://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems the regex itself is wrong. For the given JSON sample, please try:

```
"(add|alter|create|delete|drop|exec|insert|set|table|truncate|update|view)[\w% ]*":
```

Comment: This will also find the indexes :
`$matches = [["table","table","set","view"],["table","table","set","view"]]`
and always return true.
I wanted to test only the values, which is why I had `"[^:]` at the end of my regex.